# how to pass an object as parameter in objectdatasource using textbox

Tags: c#, objectdatasource

I have a Company class:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }




    //this retrieves all of the rows from database

    public List<Company> RetrieveMany(Company entity)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "RetrieveCompanys", CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyId", entity.CompanyId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", entity.Name).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;


        DataTable dt = SqlHelper.GetData(command);
        var items = new List<Company>();

        if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0) return items;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            var item = new Company();

            item.CompanyId = row["CompanyId"].GetInt();
            item.Name = row["Name"].GetString();
            item.Description = row["Description"].GetString();

            items.Add(item);
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

then I used an objectdatasource to show it in a gridview. I used the method RetrieveMany method. but my method uses object as parameter.

usually I do it like this

```
Company compObj = new Company();
compObj.Name = NameTextBox.Text;

List<Company> comps = RetrieveMany(compObj);
```

but I dont know how to do it in ObjectDataSource.

Comment: Why do you mean by `ObjectDataSource`, why not appear in above code?

Comment: @Lei Yang ObjectDataSource is a control element in asp.net